# Дискомания или диско-мания?

Tags: орфография

Как должно писаться слово, если под "диско" имеется в виду музыкальный стиль? Коллега считает, что слитно, потому что "мания" - суффиксоид. Это заглавие статьи о стиле диско - игра слов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Легитимным следует считать слитное написание "дискомания", причем слово имеет два смысла: (1) болезненная страсть к дискам; (2) любовь к музыкальному стилю диско (также название фестивалей, концертов, альбомов с такой музыкой).

Слово "мания" может управлять падежом зависимого существительного: М. величия.  М. приобретательства. Испытывать манию к домашнему уюту. Но оно не может иметь существительное в качестве приложения в препозиции, то есть написание "диско-мания" в современной орфографии не применяется (это было бы прецедентом), например: битломания.

Comment: София, а словарная фиксация многозначности дискомании есть? 2-е значение за словом закреплено?

Comment: Нет, в словарях такого значения я не видела, об этом приходится судить по факту. Практически в большинстве случаев,  и именно с этим значением, встречается только слитная форма. Конечно, есть попытки дефисного или даже раздельного написания, но они единичны и существующим правилам не соответствуют, так как  нет ни одного сложного слова на основе "мания" с дефисным написанием.

Answer (score 2):

В полном академическом справочнике сказано: . Слова с первыми частями диско- (муз.), пишутся через дефис: диско-клуб, диско-музыка. То же на Грамоте:Первая часть сложных слов диско-... (о музыкальном направлении) пишется через дефис: диско-клуб, диско-бар, диско-музыка и т. д. Но: дискобол, дисковод, дискохранилище.
Но: дискомания - греч. diskos - плоский круг, mania - влечение, страсть, безумие) - импульсивное влечение красть диски с музыкальными записями или без таковых, а затем избавляться от них или их складировать, совершенно ими не пользуясь, поскольку они, после кражи, теряют в глазах пациента всякую ценность. Известен случай, когда пациент накопил такое количество дисков, что занял ими почти всё своё жилое помещение. Вариант клептомании. Это же не музыкальное направление. Здесь имеет значение: относящийся к дискам.  В словаре словесного ударения на Грамота.ру это слово написано слитно.

Уважаемый(ая) Ами, в интернете это слово встречается только в слитном написании. А если это слово употребляется в значении музыкального направления, то не могли бы вы, пожалуйста, уточнить, какое значение оно имеет в музыкальном направлении. В интернете об этом ничего не говорится.

Дополнение. 
http://www.odnoklassniki.ru/dk?cmd=logExternal&st._aid=Conversations_Openlink&st.name=externalLinkRedirect&st.link=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.odnoklassniki.ru%2Fgroup%2F42739190202492%2Ftopic%2F62692739402620

Comment: В написании "диско-музыка" всё законно, здесь новых правил не нужно. Это словосочетание приложение+ существительное, дефисное написание приложения связано с его несклоняемостью, словосочетание в этом случае формально переходит в сложное слово. "Дискомания" в любом значении не пишется через дефис, так как в языке существует много слов на "- мания", и все они пишутся слитно на правах сложного слова, образованного из словосочетания с подчинительной связью: мания к дискам, или мания к музыкальному стилю диско, или все другие мании.

Answer (score 1):

Если Вы имеете в виду музыкальное направление, то пишете через дефис, если же болезнь, манию, то слитно.

Answer (score 1):

Музыкальное направление пишете через дефис; болезнь, манию, - слитно.